# Query an array where two other arrays align

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have 3 arrays, `x`, `y`, and `q`. Arrays `x` and `y` have the same length, `q` is a query array. Assume all values in `x` and `q` are unique. For each value of `q`, I would like to find the index of the corresponding value in `x`. I would then like to query that index in `y`. If a value from `q` does not appear in `x`, I would like to return `np.nan`.

As a concrete example, consider the following arrays:

```py
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])                                                                  
y = np.array([4, 5, 6])                                                                  
q = np.array([2, 0])
```

Since only the value 2 occurs in `x`, the correct return value would be:

```py
out = np.array([5, np.nan])
```

With for loops, this can be done like so:

```py
out = []                                                                                 
for i in range(len(q)):                                                                  
    for j in range(len(x)):                                                              
        if np.allclose(q[i], x[j]):                                                      
            out.append(y[j])                                                             
            break                                                                        
    else:                                                                                
        out.append(np.nan)                                                               
output = np.array(out)
```

Obviously this is quite slow. Is there a simpler way to do this with numpy builtins like `np.argwhere`? Or would it be easier to use pandas?

Comment: Pandas solution might involve creating a dataframe from x and y, then joining with a dataframe for q like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395360/5828163.

Comment: I doubt that creating pandas dfs would be faster than using numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy broadcasting should work.

```py
# a mask that flags any matches
m = q == x[:, None]
# replace any value in q without any match in x by np.nan
res = np.where(m.any(0), y[:, None] * m, np.nan).sum(0)
res
# array([ 5., nan])
```

I should note that this only works if `x` has no duplicates.

---

Because it relies on building a `len(x) x len(q)` array, if `q` is large, the above solution will run into memory issues. Another pandas solution will work much more efficiently in that case:

```py
# map q to y via x
res = pd.Series(q).map(pd.Series(y, index=x)).values
```

---

If `x` and `q` are 2D, it's better to convert the `Series.map()` solution into a `DataFrame.merge()` one:

```py
res = pd.DataFrame(q).merge(pd.DataFrame(x).assign(y=y), on=[0,1], how='left')['y'].values
```

Numpy broadcasting will blow up (will require 3D array) and will not be efficient for large arrays. Numba might do well though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use **np.argwhere** too. Use a more comfortable one, Pandas or numpy.

```
out_idx = [y[np.argwhere(x==value).reshape(-1)] for value in q]
out = [x[0] if len(x) else np.nan for x in out_idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could solve this in one line but using one for, and some broadcasting:

```
out = [y[bl].item() if bl.any() else None for bl in x[None,:]==q[:,None] ]
```

seems to me an elegant solution but a little confusing to read. I will go part by part.

1. `x[None,:]==q[:,None]` compares every value in q with every in x and returns `(len(q),len(x)` array of booleans (in this case will be `[[False,True,False], [False,False,False]]`
2. you can index y with a boolean array with same length `len(y)`. so you could call `y[ [False,True,False] ]` to get the value of y[1].
3. If the bool array contains all false then you have to put a `None` so that's why to use the `if-else`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
query_results = pd.DataFrame(index=q).join(pd.DataFrame({'y':y}, index=x)).T.to_numpy()[0]
```

Output:

```
[ 5. nan]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the performance is the main aim of this question, you can accelerate your looping code with numba library and jitting which will be very fast:

```
x = np.random.permutation(2000)[:1100]
y = np.random.permutation(2000)[:1100]
q = np.random.permutation(3000)[:500]
print((q > 2000).sum())


@nb.njit
def numba_(x, y, q):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(q)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            if q[i] == x[j]:
                out.append(y[j])
                break
        else:
            out.append(np.nan)
    return np.array(out)
```

or in parallel mode:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_p(x, y, q):
    out = np.empty(q.shape[0])
    out.fill(np.nan)
    for i in nb.prange(q.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[0]):
            if q[i] == x[j]:
                out[i] = y[j]
                break
    return out
```

On large arrays it was much faster than [*not a robot* answer (`np.where`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694300/13394817) and [*constantstranger* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694343/13394817) and near the same for [*not a robot* answer (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694300/13394817):

```
100 loops, best of 5: 4.4  ms per loop          <-- not a robot       (np.where)
100 loops, best of 5: 337  µs per loop          <-- not a robot       (Pandas)
100 loops, best of 5: 350  µs per loop          <-- numba
100 loops, best of 5: 341  µs per loop          <-- numba_p
100 loops, best of 5: 2.18 ms per loop          <-- constantstranger  (Pandas)
```

**Note**: [`np.where`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.23.0rc3) will be [improved much in terms of performance in the new release](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21130), which can help the *not a robot* answer beat the *constantstranger* answer on larger arrays.

**Update:** [*not a robot* answer (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694300/13394817) was much faster (the fastest) on my new test on much larger arrays.